# How do I make separate columns from one column that contains null and multiple values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I have this file converted from PDF to CSV to train a model. three columns from the pdf file have merged into one in the csv e.g the ProductID, Commodity and country.

I was trying to separate these columns with the help of regular expression, but I am not quite sure how the columns will go.

This set of data is what I am dealing with:

```
                   country/commodity Unit        Quantity      Value
1     0011101 BREEDING BULLS (OXEN)   NO            NaN          75
2                             DUBAI  NaN            NaN          75
3  0011102 BREEDING BULLS (BUFFALO)   NO            248        1921
4                         SRI LUNKA  NaN            248        1921
5          0011103 BUFFALO,BREEDING   NO            NaN          90
6                         SRI LUNKA  NaN            NaN          90
7             0011104 COWS BREEDING   NO           1249   258921665
8                             AJMAN  NaN            NaN         NaN
9                            CYPRUS  NaN            NaN         NaN
```

I need this data to be in this format:

```
0    ProductID      Commodity           Country     Unit  Quantity    Value 
1     0011101    BREEDING BULLS (OXEN)   DUBAI      NaN    NaN          75
3     0011102   BREEDING BULLS (BUFFALO) SRI LUNKA  NaN    248         1921
4     0011103   BUFFALO,BREEDING         SRI LUNKA  NaN    NaN          90            
7     0011104   COWS BREEDING            AJMAN      NaN    NaN         NaN        
8     0011104   COWS BREEDING            CYPRUS     NaN    NaN         NaN                        
9     0011104   COWS BREEDING            CHINA      NaN    590         3290
```

Comment: Where did row 9 come from?

Comment: couldn't figure out why the numbers are not consistent. But the general idea is to identify rows with product ID (use regex), separate ID and commodity and ffill ProductID and Commidity Column

Comment: @Erfan Oh that was missing in the first one. Just ignore it.

Comment: @MarkWang As you can see I need the ProductID and Commodity with a country, so the sum "numbers are not consistent" is not required. If you can figure out a way to change the first column into the three(in the second part), would be great.

Comment: @Idris, then what I mentioned in the comments should work.

Comment: @MarkWang thank you, I am working on that.

Comment: Welcome to SO; this is a standard pandas question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (please edit & remove).

Comment: @desertnaut I was preparing this data for ML training so I thought I'd put it out there. But I am sorry, I am new here asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we make your columns `ProductID, Commodity, Country` by substracting the information from the `country/commodity` column with:

- `str.split`
- `str.extract`
- `Series.where`
- `Series.mask`
- `str.contains`

Then we `GroupBy` on `ProductID` to get the information of the corresponding products together and we use `named aggregation` for this, which is new since `pandas 0.25.0`:

```
# Extract information from country/commodity
df['ProductID'] = df['country/commodity'].str.split(' ', 1).str[0].str.extract('(\d+)').ffill()
df['Commodity'] = df['country/commodity'].str.split('\d+').str[-1].where(df['Unit'].notna())
df['Country'] = df['country/commodity'].mask(df['country/commodity'].str.contains('\d+')).fillna('')

# Groupby ProductID to get information together
df_new = df.groupby(['ProductID']).agg(
    Commodity=('Commodity', 'first'),
    Country=('Country', ', '.join),
    Unit=('Unit', 'first'),
    Quantity=('Quantity', 'first'),
    Value=('Value', 'first')
).reset_index()

# Remove unnecessary comma's
df_new['Country'] = df_new['Country'].str.lstrip(', ')
```

**Output**

```
  ProductID                  Commodity        Country Unit  Quantity  \
0   0011101      BREEDING BULLS (OXEN)          DUBAI   NO       NaN   
1   0011102   BREEDING BULLS (BUFFALO)      SRI LUNKA   NO     248.0   
2   0011103           BUFFALO,BREEDING      SRI LUNKA   NO       NaN   
3   0011104              COWS BREEDING  AJMAN, CYPRUS   NO    1249.0   

         Value  
0         75.0  
1       1921.0  
2         90.0  
3  258921665.0
```